# How to create a legend in FeaturePlot with do.hover at the same time?

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat

[image]you can see in my feature plot I can only see the cells from which sample but I cannot see the legend. And if I change the command I can see the legend but cannot see the sample identities.`FeaturePlot(object = VarMerge, features.plot = c("Hcn4"), do.hover = T, no.legend = F,)`

if I change the command to

```
FeaturePlot(object = VarMerge, features.plot = c("Hcn4"), no.legend = F
```

it will show like the second picture. So I just want to know whether in the first picture can I do something to the command and add the legend like in second picture?

[image]